# Porcentaje de Riego en Mapa, Google Maps API Js

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-v3

Buenos días, estoy intentando mostrar en un mapa un porcentaje de Riego. Lo he intentado de varias maneras, por ejemplo:

-Mostrar un poligono al 50% sobre un poligono original de 100% No funcionó porque al enviar solo un 50% de las coordenadas del array para mostrar, no queda simétrico el polígono sobrepuesto.

En este caso, el polígono verde es el sobrepuesto.

[image: Polígono Sobrepuesto]

-Mostrar un label sobre el polígono. Funciona pero no fue de nuestro agrado como quedó.

-Mostrar una gráfica al dar clic, sobre el poligono. No lo usaron porque eran demasiados clics para ir de gráfica en gráfica.

-Cambiar color u opacidad del relleno del poligono.

Me gustaría poder regresar a la primer opción de mostrar un polígono sobrepuesto acorde al avance de riego.

Si alguien pudiera ayudarme con eso, muy agradecido.

```js
var map;
var infoWindow;
var avanceRiego=50;

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 18,
    center: {lat: 13.866291, lng: -90.204114},
    mapTypeId: 'terrain'
  });

  var coordenadas = [
      {lat: 13.866291, lng: -90.204114},
      {lat: 13.866325, lng: -90.204115},
      {lat: 13.866325, lng: -90.204115},
      {lat: 13.866365, lng: -90.20413},
      {lat: 13.86639,  lng: -90.20416},
      {lat: 13.86639,  lng: -90.20416},
      {lat: 13.866434, lng: -90.204177}, 
      {lat: 13.866457, lng: -90.204189}, 
      {lat: 13.866457, lng: -90.204189},
      {lat: 13.866494, lng: -90.204192},
      {lat: 13.866512, lng: -90.204298},
      {lat: 13.866507, lng: -90.204353},
      {lat: 13.866479, lng: -90.204402},
      {lat: 13.866479, lng: -90.204402},
      {lat: 13.86642,  lng: -90.204426},
      {lat: 13.86642,  lng: -90.204426},
      {lat: 13.86642,  lng: -90.204426},
      {lat: 13.866385, lng: -90.204396},
      {lat: 13.86636,  lng: -90.204366},
      {lat: 13.866353, lng: -90.204334},
      {lat: 13.866324, lng: -90.20429},
      {lat: 13.866303, lng: -90.204236},
      {lat: 13.866293, lng: -90.204177},
      {lat: 13.866282, lng: -90.20415},
      {lat: 13.866282, lng: -90.20415},
      {lat: 13.866291, lng: -90.204114}
  ];
  var poligono = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: coordenadas,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 3,
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: 0.35
  });
  poligono.setMap(map);
}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
 * element that contains the map. */
#map {
  height: 100%;
}
/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
 <!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCK3ulYYM8GCwK-_HlZVNKvkgp-zvEebUM&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```

Comment: Podrias mostrar imagenes comparativas de lo que obtienes y de lo que deseas obtener

Comment: Idea para mostrar "el 50% del polígono": `De cada polígono obtener su Bounding Box, Hacer un Bounding Box cogiendo el 50% de su altura (o anchura), Intersectar el Bounding Box generado con el polígono`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como te he comentado:

> De cada polígono:
>
> 1. Obtener su Bounding Box
> 2. Hacer un nuevoBounding Box cogiendo el 50% de su altura (o anchura)
> 3. Intersectar el Bounding Box del paso 2 con el polígono original

**NOTA:** El resultado **NO** obtiene un polígono con la mitad de área del original.

Te dejo un ejemplo práctico con Openlayers y la librería [JSTS](https://bjornharrtell.github.io/jsts/doc/api/index.html).

```js
var coordenadas = [
  {lat: 13.866291, lng: -90.204114},
  {lat: 13.866325, lng: -90.204115},
  {lat: 13.866325, lng: -90.204115},
  {lat: 13.866365, lng: -90.20413},
  {lat: 13.86639,  lng: -90.20416},
  {lat: 13.86639,  lng: -90.20416},
  {lat: 13.866434, lng: -90.204177}, 
  {lat: 13.866457, lng: -90.204189}, 
  {lat: 13.866457, lng: -90.204189},
  {lat: 13.866494, lng: -90.204192},
  {lat: 13.866512, lng: -90.204298},
  {lat: 13.866507, lng: -90.204353},
  {lat: 13.866479, lng: -90.204402},
  {lat: 13.866479, lng: -90.204402},
  {lat: 13.86642,  lng: -90.204426},
  {lat: 13.86642,  lng: -90.204426},
  {lat: 13.86642,  lng: -90.204426},
  {lat: 13.866385, lng: -90.204396},
  {lat: 13.86636,  lng: -90.204366},
  {lat: 13.866353, lng: -90.204334},
  {lat: 13.866324, lng: -90.20429},
  {lat: 13.866303, lng: -90.204236},
  {lat: 13.866293, lng: -90.204177},
  {lat: 13.866282, lng: -90.20415},
  {lat: 13.866282, lng: -90.20415},
  {lat: 13.866291, lng: -90.204114}
];

var parserJSTS = new jsts.io.OL3Parser();

var poly = new ol.Feature({
  geometry: new ol.geom.Polygon([coordenadas.map(({lng, lat})=>[lng, lat])])
})

var boundingBox = poly.getGeometry().getExtent()
var polybbox = new ol.Feature({
  geometry: ol.geom.Polygon.fromExtent(boundingBox)
})

var [xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax] = boundingBox
var porcentaje = 0.25
var newXmax = xmin + ((xmax - xmin) * porcentaje)

var newBoundingBox = [xmin, ymin, newXmax, ymax]

var polybbox50 = new ol.Feature({
  geometry: ol.geom.Polygon.fromExtent(newBoundingBox)
})

var polybbox50jsts = parserJSTS.read(polybbox50.getGeometry())

var polyjsts = parserJSTS.read(poly.getGeometry())

var intersectionJSTSGeometry = polyjsts.intersection(polybbox50jsts)

var intersectionGeometry = parserJSTS.write(intersectionJSTSGeometry)

var newPoly = new ol.Feature({ geometry: intersectionGeometry })
//console.log(boundingBox)

newPoly.setStyle(new ol.style.Style({
  fill: new ol.style.Fill({
    color: '#ffbb00'
  })
}))

var layer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: new ol.source.Vector()
})

// Descomentar para ver los bounding boxes
//layer.getSource().addFeature(polybbox)
//layer.getSource().addFeature(polybbox50)
layer.getSource().addFeature(poly)
layer.getSource().addFeature(newPoly)


var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM()
    }),
    layer
  ],
  target: 'map',
  controls: ol.control.defaults({
    attributionOptions:({
      collapsible: false
    })
  }),
  view: new ol.View({
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 2,
    projection: 'EPSG:4326'
  })
});

map.getView().fit(boundingBox)
```

```css
#map {
  height: 100%;
}
/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsts/1.5.0/jsts.js"></script>
<script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.5.0/build/ol-debug.js"></script>
<link href="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.5.0/css/ol.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="map" class="map" tabindex="0"></div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias José, lo pondré en práctica. Gracias por tu valiosa ayuda.

Comment: De nada =) para eso estamos! Te dejo también la documentación de JSTS que te servirá de mucha ayuda.

Comment: También comentar que si el polígono tiene anillos interiores, pudiera haber soluciones mejores. Pero si los polígonos son Simples (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_polygon) funcionará bien.

Comment: Con JSTS crees que sea posible integrarlo a los mapas de google maps?

Comment: Sí, lo bueno de JSTS es que para Openlayers ya te viene un parser de Geometrías de Openlayers 3, y es más cómodo trabajar. No he usado desde hace mucho la API de Google Maps (Soy más de OL). Puedes buscar información al respecto, por ejemplo en esta pregunta: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26037104/how-to-calculate-intersection-area-in-google-maps-api-with-jsts-library

Comment: Aquí tienes un ejemplo de integración (No lo he hecho yo) https://jsfiddle.net/vgrem/3ukpuxq9/

Comment: Oooh genial, muchas gracias. Una pregunta, en el caso de open layers cual es la mejor capa para mostrar el mapa como vista de satelite. He probado ahorita con Bing y Stamen. Tambien estoy intentanto replicar tu ejemplo de open layer con google maps pero no lo logro todavía.

Comment: Según la cobertura que quieras. Puedes usar Bing(Esto te requiere de una API Key). Puedes consultar en la web si tu país dispone de algún Geoportal con servicios WMS que te sirvan Ortofotos de la zona en cuestión.

Comment: Estoy tratando de implementar tu ejemplo en una funcion donde genero las coordenadas pero me da error en var Poly . function crearPoligonos(coordenada) {
            
    var coordenadas = coordenada.split(' ') 
 .map(function(data) {
  var info = data.split(','), 
   coord = { 
    lat: parseFloat(info[1]),
    lng: parseFloat(info[0])
   };
  return coord;
 });

    var parserJSTS = new jsts.io.OL3Parser();

    var poly = new ol.Feature({
        geometry: new ol.geom.Polygon([coordenadas.map(({lng, lat})=>[lng, lat])])
    })
    
  }

Comment: Con esos datos no puedo ayudarte, lo siento. Abre otra pregunta con el error específico que tengas. Intenta reproducir tu error en el snippet. Como sugerencia prueba a usar la librería `ol-debug.js` que puede mostrarte los errores de forma más amigable.

Comment: Gracias José, tu ayuda me ha sido de gran ayuda para poder avanzar. Abrí el nuevo tema ya que preferí aprender con openlayers y no quedarme solo con google maps.

Comment: Disculpa la molestia, lo que no logro hacer es cambiar el tamaño del polygono de 50% a por ejemplo 10%, gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: Ahí lo tienes. Mira la edición.