# Reducir tamaño del BoundingBox con Google Maps Api JS y Jsts

Tags: javascript, google-maps-v3

Buen día estoy intentando reducir el tamaño del BoundingBox de un Poligono con GoogleMaps Api Js. Lo que deseo obtener es que a partir del valor en una variable muestre X porcentaje del BoundingBox para mostrar un porcentaje de llenado en el poligono.

Anteriormente me ayudaron con un ejemplo con OpenLayers y Jsts, el problema que no logro replicar ese ejemplo con Google Maps y Jsts.

Si alguien puede ayudarme muy agradecido.

Este es el link, del ejemplo que me dieron con OpenLayers: [Porcentaje de Riego en Mapa, Google Maps API Js](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/121510/porcentaje-de-riego-en-mapa-google-maps-api-js)

Y aquí con google maps.

```js
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: { lat: 24.886, lng: -70.268 },
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.terrain
  });

  // Define the LatLng coordinates for the polygon's path.
  var bermudaCoords = [
    { lat: 25.774, lng: -80.190 },
    { lat: 18.466, lng: -66.118 },
    { lat: 32.321, lng: -64.757 },
    { lat: 25.774, lng: -80.190 }
  ];

  // Construct the polygon.
  var bermudaTriangle = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: bermudaCoords,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: 0.35
  });
  bermudaTriangle.setMap(map);
  
  var triBnds = new google.maps.Rectangle({
    map: map,
    bounds: polygonBounds(bermudaTriangle)
  })
console.log(polygonBounds(bermudaTriangle));
  // Construct another polygon.
  var anotherCoords = [
    { lat: 25.774, lng: -85.101 },
    { lat: 35.406, lng: -85.101 },
    { lat: 35.406, lng: -54.127 },
    { lat: 25.774, lng: -60.010 }
  ];

  var anotherArea = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: anotherCoords,
    strokeColor: '#0000FF',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: '#0000FF',
    fillOpacity: 0.35
  });
  anotherArea.setMap(map);
    var otherBnds = new google.maps.Rectangle({
    map: map,
    bounds: polygonBounds(anotherArea)
  })



  //calc polygons intersection
  var geometryFactory = new jsts.geom.GeometryFactory();
  var bermudaPolygon = createJstsPolygon(geometryFactory, bermudaTriangle);
  var anotherPolygon = createJstsPolygon(geometryFactory, anotherArea);
  var intersection = bermudaPolygon.intersection(anotherPolygon);
  drawIntersectionArea(map, intersection);
}



function drawIntersectionArea(map, polygon) {
  var coords = polygon.getCoordinates().map(function (coord) {
    return { lat: coord.x, lng: coord.y };
  });

  var intersectionArea = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: coords,
    strokeColor: '#00FF00',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 4,
    fillColor: '#00FF00',
    fillOpacity: 0.35
  });
  intersectionArea.setMap(map);
}



function createJstsPolygon(geometryFactory, polygon) {
  var path = polygon.getPath();
  var coordinates = path.getArray().map(function name(coord) {
    return new jsts.geom.Coordinate(coord.lat(), coord.lng());
  });
  coordinates.push(coordinates[0]);
  var shell = geometryFactory.createLinearRing(coordinates);
  return geometryFactory.createPolygon(shell);
}

function polygonBounds(polygon) {

   var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
   for (var i=0; i<polygon.getPaths().getLength(); i++) {
     for (var j=0; j<polygon.getPaths().getAt(i).getLength(); j++) {
        bounds.extend(polygon.getPaths().getAt(i).getAt(j));
     }
   }
   return bounds;
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
```

```css
 #map,
        html,
        body {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            height: 100%;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=drawing"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/bjornharrtell/jsts/gh-pages/1.1.2/jsts.min.js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si el postulado es:

> dado un polígono, dibujar encima de él otro polígono que represente un
>   cierto porcentaje del área del primero

Se me ocurre cómo hacerlo usando [Turf.js](http://turfjs.org)  (disclaimer, participo del desarrollo de Turf, aunque de manera muy tangencial)

**PERO** esta solución no parte desde el vértice superior sino desde el centroide. pasa que la función [transformScale](http://turfjs.org/Docs/#transformScale) de Turf saca un clon a escala del polígono original, dibujándolo en una posición que por defecto es `centroid`, **también puedes poner que parta de una de las esquinas del bounding box**, pero la esquina superior izquierda de tu triángulo haría que la copia a escala quedara fuera del polígono original.

A continuación, el ejemplo usando `0.5` como factor.

```js
function latlngs_to_coords(latlngs) {
  return latlngs.map(function(latlng) {
     return [latlng.lng(),latlng.lat()];
 });
}

function coords_to_latlngs(coords) {
  return coords.map(function(coord) {
   return {lat:coord[1],lng:coord[0]};
 });
}

function scale_poly(poly,factor){
  return turf.transformScale(poly, Math.sqrt(factor));
}

function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: { lat: 24.786, lng: -70.268 },
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.terrain
  });

  // Define the LatLng coordinates for the polygon's path.
  var bermudaCoords = [
    { lat: 25.774, lng: -80.190 },
    { lat: 18.466, lng: -66.118 },
    { lat: 32.321, lng: -64.757 },
    { lat: 25.774, lng: -80.190 }
  ];

  // Construct the polygon.
  var bermudaTriangle = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: bermudaCoords,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: 0.35
  });
  bermudaTriangle.setMap(map);
  
 var coordinates=latlngs_to_coords(bermudaTriangle.getPath().getArray());
 var polygon = turf.polygon([coordinates]);
 var scaledPoly = scale_poly(polygon,0.5);
 var latlngs=coords_to_latlngs(scaledPoly.geometry.coordinates[0]);
 
  var bermudaScaled = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: latlngs,
    strokeColor: '#00FF00',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: '#00FF00',
    fillOpacity: 0.35
  });
  bermudaScaled.setMap(map);
   
}
 
 
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
```

```css
#map,
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBRqo4qwqHHrtbY9aL6vYYDw1GOhkK97MQ"></script>

<script src='https://npmcdn.com/@turf/turf/turf.min.js'></script>

<div id="map"></div>
```

La figura puede ser engañosa. Mal que mal, un triángulo de la mitad de área tendría sus lados de un largo de más o menos 0.7 veces el largo de los lados originales. (o sea 1/(raíz de 2))

Comment: Hola amenadiel, actualmente los muestro solo como referencia pero al final no debo mostrarlos. Lo que busco es poder reducir el tamaño del bounding box según el valor de una variable así podre reducir el largo del poligono y poder mostrarlo con la interseccion y llenar solo un porcentaje de ese polígono. Así como los ejemplos que dejé adjuntos.Gracias por tu ayuda ya que lo he intentando pero aún no lo logro.

Comment: Entonces quieres deducir las coordenadas del trapezoide a partir del porcentaje que quieres oscurecer. Pero es un porcentaje del área o de la altura?

Comment: Si exacto, es a partir del porcentaje. Seria a la altura la que reduciría, así podríamos ver el triángulo con un porcentaje de llenado. Por ejemplo si es un 50% debe aparecer el polígono completo, pero su relleno osea la intersección solo ocuparía el 50%. Como que fuera ub vaso con agua hasta la mitad. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Se me ocurre como hacerlo, pero no partiendo desde el tope sino desde el centroide. Voy a editar mi respuesta a ver si te sirve

Comment: Intentaré usar tu respuesta, muy agradecido. Ya que debo mostrar estos poligonos para avances de corte de caña de azucar. Entonces debo poder mostrar que porcentaje del poligono ya fue cortado. Casi siempre los poligonos que utilizare son rectangulos, o poligonos de un mapa. Veré si puedo adecuarlo a lo que necesito. Muy agradecido.

Comment: Lo intente utilizar con estas coordenadas, pero al parecer no es compatible var bermudaCoords = [{ lat: 13.866291, lng: -90.204114 },{ lat: 13.866325, lng: -90.204115 },{ lat: 13.866325, lng: -90.204115 },{ lat: 13.866365, lng: -90.20413 },{ lat: 13.86639, lng: -90.20416 },{ lat: 13.86639, lng: -90.20416 },{ lat: 13.866434, lng: -90.204177 },{ lat: 13.866457, lng: -90.204189 },{ lat: 13.866457, lng: -90.204189 },{ lat: 13.866494, lng: -90.204192 },{ lat: 13.866512, lng: -90.204298 },{ lat: 13.866507, lng: -90.204353 },{ lat: 13.866479, lng: -90.204402 },{ lat: 13.866479, lng: -90.204402 }];

Comment: @raintrooper Turf necesita que le pases un anillo cerrado. Si le añades la primera coordenada al final del array, te va a funcionar. https://plnkr.co/edit/XIFWdrMQOKGI9GsbEXmg?p=preview (puedes añadir una comprobación en la función `latlngs_to_coords` o derechamente siempre añadir esa coordenada.