# Modificar tamaño de Bounding Box con Google Maps Api y Jsts

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Buen día, estoy intentanto reducir el tamaño del Bounding Box, pero aún no logro hacerlo. Lo que necesito hacer es reducir del largo del poligono. Considero que debo obtener las coordenadas de cada esquina, pero no ubico la función para hacerlo.

Al ver el resultado en la consola, logro ver lo siguiente:

[image: Coordenadas]

Esas coordenadas, son las esquinas que obtengo en:

```
function polygonBounds(polygon) {
   var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
   for (var i=0; i<polygon.getPaths().getLength(); i++) {
      for (var j=0; j<polygon.getPaths().getAt(i).getLength(); j++) {
      bounds.extend(polygon.getPaths().getAt(i).getAt(j));

  console.log(bounds.extend(polygon.getPaths().getAt(i).getAt(j)));
  }
}
 return bounds;
}
```

[image: Consola]

Lo que busco es poder reducir el tamaño del boundingbox de derecha a izquierda, y ya con esto poder hacer una intersección con otro poligono y así poder mostrar solo una parte llena del poligono.

[image: Fill Poligono]

Pero no he podido avanzar más, al no poder reducir el tamaño del bounding box.

```js
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: { lat: 24.886, lng: -70.268 },
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
  });

  // Define the LatLng coordinates for the polygon's path.
  var bermudaCoords = [
    { lat: 25.774, lng: -80.190 },
    { lat: 18.466, lng: -66.118 },
    { lat: 32.321, lng: -64.757 },
    { lat: 25.774, lng: -80.190 }
  ];

  // Construct the polygon.
  var bermudaTriangle = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: bermudaCoords,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: 0.35
  });
  
  bermudaTriangle.setMap(map);
  var triBnds = new google.maps.Rectangle({
    map: map,
    bounds: polygonBounds(bermudaTriangle)
  })

  //calc polygons intersection
  var geometryFactory = new jsts.geom.GeometryFactory();
  var bermudaPolygon = createJstsPolygon(geometryFactory, bermudaTriangle);
}

function createJstsPolygon(geometryFactory, polygon) {
  var path = polygon.getPath();
  var coordinates = path.getArray().map(function name(coord) {
    return new jsts.geom.Coordinate(coord.lat(), coord.lng());
  });
  coordinates.push(coordinates[0]);
  var shell = geometryFactory.createLinearRing(coordinates);
  return geometryFactory.createPolygon(shell);
}

function polygonBounds(polygon) {
   var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
   for (var i=0; i<polygon.getPaths().getLength(); i++) {
     for (var j=0; j<polygon.getPaths().getAt(i).getLength(); j++) {
        bounds.extend(polygon.getPaths().getAt(i).getAt(j));
        console.log(bounds.extend(polygon.getPaths().getAt(i).getAt(j)));
     }
   }
   return bounds;
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
```

```css
#map,
        html,
        body {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            height: 100%;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=drawing"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/bjornharrtell/jsts/gh-pages/1.1.2/jsts.min.js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: Lo que busco es poder reducir el tamaño del boundingbox de derecha a izquierda, y ya con esto poder hacer una intersección con otro polígono y así poder mostrar solo una parte llena del polígono. Así como en la imagen que acabo de agregar a la pregunta. Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo difícil de la pregunta es conocer la API de Google Maps (Para mi gusto personal, algo liosa y poco intuitiva, razón por la cual suelo usar Openlayers).

Debes guiarte por la documentación y buscar los métodos que necesitas.

Este es el código para obtener un nuevo Bounding Box:

```
const bounds = polygonBounds(bermudaTriangle)

const esquinaInferiorIzquierda = bounds.getSouthWest()
const esquinaSuperiorDerecha = bounds.getNorthEast()

const xmin = esquinaInferiorIzquierda.lng()
const ymin = esquinaInferiorIzquierda.lat()

const xmax = esquinaSuperiorDerecha.lng()
const ymax = esquinaSuperiorDerecha.lat()

const newXmax = xmin + (xmax - xmin)*0.25

const newEsquinaInferiorIzquierda = {
  lng: xmin,
  lat: ymin
}

const newEsquinaSuperiorDerecha = {
  lng: newXmax,
  lat: ymax
}

const newBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
  newEsquinaInferiorIzquierda,
  newEsquinaSuperiorDerecha
)
```

---

Para lo demás mi recomendación es que te guíes de mi [otra respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/121510/porcentaje-de-riego-en-mapa-google-maps-api-js/121536#121536) y sobre todo la documentación de las librerías que estás usando

```js
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: { lat: 24.886, lng: -70.268 },
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
  });

  // Define the LatLng coordinates for the polygon's path.
  var bermudaCoords = [
    { lat: 25.774, lng: -80.190 },
    { lat: 18.466, lng: -66.118 },
    { lat: 32.321, lng: -64.757 },
    { lat: 25.774, lng: -80.190 }
  ];

  // Construct the polygon.
  var bermudaTriangle = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: bermudaCoords,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: 0.35
  });
  
  bermudaTriangle.setMap(map);
  
  const bounds = polygonBounds(bermudaTriangle)

  const esquinaInferiorIzquierda = bounds.getSouthWest()
  const esquinaSuperiorDerecha = bounds.getNorthEast()

  const xmin = esquinaInferiorIzquierda.lng()
  const ymin = esquinaInferiorIzquierda.lat()

  const xmax = esquinaSuperiorDerecha.lng()
  const ymax = esquinaSuperiorDerecha.lat()

  const newXmax = xmin + (xmax - xmin)*0.25

  const newEsquinaInferiorIzquierda = {
    lng: xmin,
    lat: ymin
  }

  const newEsquinaSuperiorDerecha = {
    lng: newXmax,
    lat: ymax
  }

  const newBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
    newEsquinaInferiorIzquierda,
    newEsquinaSuperiorDerecha
  )
  
  var triBnds = new google.maps.Rectangle({
    map: map,
    bounds: newBounds
  })

  //calc polygons intersection
  var geometryFactory = new jsts.geom.GeometryFactory();
  var bermudaPolygon = createJstsPolygon(geometryFactory, bermudaTriangle);
}

function createJstsPolygon(geometryFactory, polygon) {
  var path = polygon.getPath();
  var coordinates = path.getArray().map(function name(coord) {
    return new jsts.geom.Coordinate(coord.lat(), coord.lng());
  });
  coordinates.push(coordinates[0]);
  var shell = geometryFactory.createLinearRing(coordinates);
  return geometryFactory.createPolygon(shell);
}

function polygonBounds(polygon) {
   var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
   for (var i=0; i<polygon.getPaths().getLength(); i++) {
     for (var j=0; j<polygon.getPaths().getAt(i).getLength(); j++) {
        bounds.extend(polygon.getPaths().getAt(i).getAt(j));
     }
   }
   return bounds;
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
```

```css
#map,
        html,
        body {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            height: 100%;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=drawing"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/bjornharrtell/jsts/gh-pages/1.1.2/jsts.min.js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias José, te agradezco la ayuda. Me servirá de mucho, ya que estuve batallando con este problema ya desde hace tiempo. Intenté de muchas maneras lograr lo que programaste, pero no logré llegar a hacerlo funcionar.

Comment: Ánimo. Seguro que con lo que te he comentado lo resuelves! Mucha suerte! =)

Comment: Gracias José, solo una duda disculpa. Al reducir el BoundingBox tambien debo reducir el poligono para que solo se muestre acorde al BoundingBox es correcto? Muchas gracias.

Comment: No te entiendo. Te refieres a realizar la intersección para mostrar el polígonos "al porcentaje" que deseas?

Comment: Mi duda es si cuando reduces el BoundingBox, también debería reducirse el polígono de ese BoundingBox? esto sin tomar en cuenta todavía la intersección. Ahora bien asi es como llevo actualmente el código. https://jsfiddle.net/3ukpuxq9/188/

Comment: No, ya que luego, la intersección del BBOX reducido con el polígono original dará como resultado la porción del polígono que quieres.

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda, José. Saludos.